# Why is the submit button not breaking on word in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, submit

There is text on the right sidebar with the words 'Subscribe to English Communication'

Now this works great on firefox, but not here on chrome. In Chrome it does Subscribe to English Communicatio and the n splits to the next line which is weird.

This is the relevant css

```
.pane-subscription #edit-subscribe {
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
padding: 5px 7px;
border: none;
width: 100%;
-ms-border-radius: 3px;
-o-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Any idea where I am messing up?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't support `word-break` and `hyphens` yet. I suggest you use a `<br />` or a separate `div`.

Comment: How do I use a <br/> for something that is being fetched dynamically depending on the category? Makes no sense

Comment: you are not going to get 'Subscribe to' part from the DB right? Can't you use the <br/> after that?

Comment: But some of their categories are so long, I will still face that issue. They have Pre and Post Submission. Even this might break.

Comment: Found out that, when applying `break-all` Lines may break between any two letters! So that is why Chrome is behaving like that